# Starcraft 2 Protoss: Can't Use My Resources Effectively

Tags: starcraft-2, starcraft-protoss

So I have this macro trouble of mine.I am currently a gold league Protoss player and playing WoL at the moment.
The problem is, I end up having over 1k minerals and can't properly waste them all! Last match I didnt have enough gateways so I had little army supply.My APM stands around 60-90 in my matches.What can I do to improve my macro or not to ask generally; how can I use all my resources fast and effective enough?

Comment: build enough production buildings to build more units at the same time at a quicker rate? This seems rather obvious to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I am not pro, expanding is one way to dump minerals. The more expansions, the more bases you can have, so when you loose one you could quickly come back trough another base.
Sacrifice units in combat, put pressure by constantly attacking with lower tier units, unless opponent will steam roll your units that is. Get upgrades and research, having two or more upgrade structures isn't *that* bad in mid to late game. You can also dump resources into building proxy structures. While gateways can warp in to any pylon, robo and stargate(?) can not

This is at least what I've learned from watching hundreds of matches, both low and high league ones.

Comment: Keep in mind that more expansions = more resources so unless he's building exponentially more tech / production buildings as he expands, his problem will just be that much worse by continuously expanding.

Comment: Well, yes, but early game expansions will drain some resources before it produces enough to keep itself up. This will also count for any further expansions. Late game is mostly just a matter of pumping out units faster than the opponent so you can finally overwhelm them.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to know the answer here. Build more gateways. Zealots are going to be your easiest mineral dump. Spend some APM each game getting out a warp prism and/or some good proxy pylon placement and do some zealot runs by.

Answer (score -1):

Mwell, in your case Rivian, I suppose you only have extra gold and no extra gaz. If it's a common situation for you, it means that you have an issue in your Build Orders and/or in your spends. 
IMO, spending your extra mineral in zealots is not a good strategy once you have reach silver or gold league. You don't even need more gates or morge tech buildings because they won't be efficient if your don't have enough gaz.

What you need is more gaz !

The best way to obtain more gaz is to expend, then, use your mineral to protect your base with photons.

I desagree with Sharain on many points. If a good player manage to have a low cash, it doe'snt mean that you must waste it if you have too much mineral. Low cash is'nt the goal but a result of a certain gameplay. Build more tech buildings, build proxy pylons, waste zealotts, this is not a good strategy if its only purpose is to clear your mineral stack.

Comment: I leveled up to Platin now, my only problem left is my hotkeys.

Comment: I can give you some usefull tips if you want